# Laravel - why do we need service providers when we can do it with the service container

Tags: laravel, service-provider

In my Laravel project, it seems to me that what I can achieve through a service provider can also be done by the service container without using any service provider.

Let me show how I can achieve the goal using either approach:

**Service provider approach:**

In my project inside `app/Service` I have the files `AwesomeServiceInterface.php` and `AwesomeService.php`.

Inside `AwesomeServiceInterface.php` file, I have :

```
namespace App\Service;

interface AwesomeServiceInterface
{
    public function doAwesomeThing();
}
```

Inside `AwesomeService.php` file , I have :

```
namespace App\Service;

class AwesomeService implements AwesomeServiceInterface
{
    public function doAwesomeThing()
    {
        echo 'do awesome thing !!!';
    }
}
```

In   the `config/app.php` file , I have added to the `'providers'` array the following line :

```
App\Providers\AwesomeServiceProvider::class,
```

Inside `app/Providers`, I have the file `AwesomeServiceProvider.php` that contains :

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Service\AwesomeServiceInterface', 'App\Service\AwesomeService');
    }
```

Inside `HomeController.php`, I have :

```
use App\Service\AwesomeServiceInterface;
  ........
  public function doAwesome(AwesomeServiceInterface $awesome_service)
    {
        $awesome_service->doAwesomeThing();
        return '';

    }
```

In `routes/web.php`, I have :

```
Route::get('/awesome', 'HomeController@doAwesome')->name('awesome');
```

Now when I hit the URL `/awesome`, I get what I expected i.e. `do awesome thing !!!`

**Service container approach :**

Without creating any service provider (i.e. `AwesomeServiceProvider`), I have inside the `register` method of `AppServiceProvider.php` at `app/Providers`  :

```
 public function register()
    {

        $this->app->bind('App\Service\AwesomeServiceInterface','App\Service\AwesomeService');

    }
```

This time I could also hit the URL `/awesome` and get the same output as before.

So **Q1)** why do I need any service provider in the above scenario ?

**Q2)** in which case do I need a service provider that I cannot achieve the goal with service container only i.e. without using any service provider ?

Comment: watch this https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/22

Comment: excerpt or summary from the link will be revealing.

Comment: you are using a service provider in both examples .....................................

Comment: @lagbox, so where is the service container ? I do not see it.

Comment: `$this->app` is the service (application) container

Comment: @lagbox, any reference in the doc regarding this ?

Comment: the service container docs https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/container#binding-basics ... the service provider docs https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/providers#writing-service-providers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205564/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-lagbox).

Comment: So why do we need to create another service provider when we have the built in `AppServiceProvider` ?

Comment: A service provider is classes that can hold logic that utilizes the service container. Multiple service providers, is just for single responsibility principle to separate the logic.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed you don't "need" to create any service providers, you could have just 1 if you really wanted to for your entire application ... its just a means to bind things to the container and bootstrap things

Comment: @lagbox, is there any special case that I have to make a service provider myself ?